# Magento Collection: incorrect product category ID in URL

Tags: magento, collections, url-rewriting

I'm looking to display a featured products collection, based on a featured attribute filter. I get this basically working okay. The part I'm struggling with is that the URL that gets attached to 'getProductUrl()' is wrong.

Comparing the system urls without rewriting them, I noticed that I get this type of url:

catalog/product/view/id/1148/category/**6**

The category ID at the end is wrong. It shows the parent category ID. If I could get the correct subcategory ID in which those products are assigned, at the end of this URL, then my rewrite would probably work.

Here's my current code, in a featured.phtml template:

```
<?php

    // get all products that are marked as featured
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('featured', array('Yes' => true));
    $collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc');
    $collection->addUrlRewrite($categoryId);

?>
```

and

```
<?php foreach ($collection as $_product) : ?>
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Additional notes: the products are in a subcategory but this collection is pulled on the landing page of its parent category and on the home CMS page.

I get: www.sitename.com/product_url_key.html

I want:  www.sitename.com/category_path/product_url_key.html